# c# boxing with value types

Tags: c#

coming from a c++ background, i'm always confused about valuetypes.
If you call a constructor on a valuetype, does it always cause boxing?
For example,

```
public struct myvaltype
{
    public int x;
    public int y;


    public myvaltype(int thisx,int thisy)
    {
        x = thisx;
        y = thisy;
    }

}

myvaltype tsts1 = new myvaltype();
myvaltype tsts2 = new myvaltype(8, 9);
```

do both of these constructor calls causes boxing?
if yes, then the only way to avoid boxing is to set each member objects (x,y) manually?

Comment: Why would you expect any boxing in this example?

Comment: Coming from C++ it should be easy in using value types in C# . C# behaves similar to C++ if you imagine `*` in every reference type (like imagine `string` as really "string*" as it is reference type). C# have similar issues related to default shallow copy and mistakenly modifying temporary copies of value types...

Answer (score 3):

No, **there is no boxing here**.

> Boxing is the process of converting a value type to the type object or to any interface type implemented by this value type.
>
> *from [Boxing and Unboxing (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)*

You're not casting (implicitly or explicitly) value type to `object` or interface.

There would be boxing (and unboxing) if your constructor looked like that:

```
public myvaltype(object thisx, object thisy)
{
    x = (int)thisx;
    y = (int)thisy;
}
```